# Trying to calculate new average score based on two dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

[Sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeVkK.png)Create a new column of a "new average score" based on 'Rating' and 'Metascore', but lets not include the 'Rating' if there are less than 100 votes (ie. base it just on the metascore)

```
import pandas 

if DF1["Votes"].all() < 100:
    DF1["New Average Score"] = DF1["Metascore"]
    else:
    DF1["New Average Score"] = DF1[['Metascore', 'Rating']].mean(axis=1)


DF1["New Average Score"]
```

I keep getting a syntax error on the 'else' statement, not sure where I went wrong
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeVkK.png)

Comment: please provide a sample of the data

Comment: Check the indentation of "else" it should  below the "if"

Answer (score 0):

There you must have an error because the else statement must be at "same level" as the "if". Your code should be write like this instead:

```
import pandas 

if DF1["Votes"].all() < 100:
    DF1["New Average Score"] = DF1["Metascore"]
else:
    DF1["New Average Score"] = DF1[['Metascore', 'Rating']].mean(axis=1)


DF1["New Average Score"]
```

Comment: Works now! Thanks so much, still learning here. Appreciate it!